# How can I set var values for products for the duration of a user's session?

Tags: php, session, variables, scope

I'm looping through an inventory of products and setting `variable` values to identify product attributes which intersect with the customer's desired attributes. What would be a reasonably efficient way to set the `variable` values for each product for the duration of a customer's session (or at least while they remain on that page)? At present the `variable`'s value doesn't seem to be preserved for each product's id beyond the scope of the initial `while` statement that assigns it.

Each variable is an indication of whether or not a particular attribute matches the customer's list of desired attributes. Instead of having to run a query countless times, I'm trying to essentially assign tags (temporarily) to each product to indicate which attributes match/don't match for that customer.

I'm doing this dynamically for 100-200 variables (using `variable variables`), so I've posted a simplified code snippet below.

```
 $Matches_Pr_Color = "Null";
 $colors_love_AR = array('Black','Charcoal','Light_Gray','White','Royal_Blue','Dodger_Blue','Red');

try {   
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");       
    $stmt->execute();           
} catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();} 
  if ($stmt->columnCount()) {
      while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {   
          $Pr_Color=$row['Color'];                          
          if (in_array($Pr_Color, $colors_love_AR)){    
              $Matches_Pr_Color = "True";
              }
          else {                   
              $Matches_Pr_Color = "False";
                }                                   
              echo $Matches_Pr_Color, "<br/>"; 
          }   
  }  
  if ($Matches_Pr_Color == "True") {
        echo  $row['product_id'].', '.$row['Color'], "<br/>";
   }
  else {
      echo  $row['product_id'], " No Match<br/>"; 
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is not clear what your problem is

Comment: @Steve - The var value isn't remaining set for each product's id beyond the scope of the initial WHILE statement that assigns it :-(

Comment: `if ($Matches_Color = "True")` I had a feeling that was a typo. Answer deleted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good catch, but sadly that wasn't the problem :-(

Comment: There isn't enough code to go on. Use error checking see if it yields anything `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

right after the connection is opened, if you're not already doing so, while replacing `$pdo` with your PDO connection variable plus `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's not throwing any errors, but I added more of the code so hopefully something will jump out at you ;-)

Comment: Try switching these `if (in_array($Pr_Color, $colors_love_AR)){` to `if (in_array($colors_love_AR, $Pr_Color)){` - just a hunch.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That just made them all "False" ;-) But it did at least allow it to run the 'ElSE' statement and echo "No Match"

Comment: *Hm...*, can we call it some form of success? I'll upvote the question, see if anyone else picks up on it.

Comment: Well, `$Matches_Pr_Color` is overwritten in each iteration of the loop, so your final if/else block will be based upon the last result in the loop. I doubt this is intended but i cant work out what you are trying to do

Comment: @Steve - I just discovered that by moving around the if/else statement :-) Is a count+ the way to do it, and if it is, how in the world do I connect that with the product's id?

Comment: @Steve - I'm trying to assign a value to the var for each product, with the value indicating whether or not it matches what the customer's looking for (so the value is specific to a user's session)

Comment: Either move the if/else within the while loop, or if you need to access the results outside of the loop, save them into an array, perhaps indexed by product id

Comment: @Steve - That's exactly what I'm trying to figure out how to do (accessing them outside the loop):-D Can you show me how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to store the results for use outside the loop, use an array, eg:

```
$colors_love_AR = array('Black','Charcoal','Light_Gray','White','Royal_Blue','Dodger_Blue','Red');
$size_love_AR = array(16,18,20);
$material_love_AR = array('leather','tweed','cotton');

$results = array();
if ($stmt->columnCount()) {
      while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
          $product_data=array();                         
          $product_data['color'] = in_array($row['Color'], $colors_love_AR);       
          $product_data['size'] = in_array($row['Size'], $size_love_AR); 
          $product_data['material'] = in_array($row['Material'], $material_love_AR);  

          $results[$row['product_id']] = $product_data;                         
      }   
}
```

This will create an array of product data indexed by the product_id, eg:

```
array(
       1=> array('color'=>true, 'size'=>false, 'material'=>true),
       2=> array('color'=>false, 'size'=>false, 'material'=>true),
       3=> array('color'=>true, 'size'=>true, 'material'=>false),
       //etc 
     );
```

You can use the array in later code like so:

```
if($results[2]['color'])
    //product with id 2 is a match for this customers color choice
```

Comment: Do I need to do this separately for each variable (i.e. $Matches_Pr_Color), or is there a way to combine them in some sort of array of arrays?

Comment: @ChayaCooper Well you can certainly have multidimensional arrays, but i still cant really fathom what you are trying to do, so i cant give a more specific example

Comment: Each variable is an indication of whether or not a particular attribute matches the customer's list of desired attributes. Instead of having to run a query countless times, I'm trying to essentially assign tags to each product to indicate which attributes match/don't match for that customer

Comment: @ChayaCooper I get that, just not how you intend to use these variables later on. If you just want to be able to tell if a certain product_id is a match for the current customer, then perhaps my edit will help

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding ;-) Since each product has a long list of attributes (bet. 100-200) and it's rare for every attribute to be a match, I need to be able to reference the specific attributes that match. I'm planning on slicing & dicing the info in several different ways including products that match on specific attribute/s, and by ranking based on weights that are being assigned to attributes, etc.

Comment: @ChayaCooper OK, so colour was just an example, you would also like to match, for example, size, material etc.  Whilst the code for ranking etc is beyond the scope of this question, i will ammend my answer to show you how you could save exta details to this array

Comment: @ChayaCooper Edited, to show how to collect and access extra data

Comment: It looks great :-) The only problem is that I'm having a hard figuring out how to print any of the array values to test it out ;-)